# Why is there empty space at the top & bottom of my page when the UWP app runs? XAML nor Design view shows empty space

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

Why does my UWP (Universal Windows Platform) App force extra space at the top and bottom of my app even though there is nothing there?

Here's what it looks like:
[image: extra space]

Even though in Visual Studio 2013 (design mode) you can see that the blue bounding box displays the bottom of the page as follows:

[image: design mode]

The outer grey is the device it would be running on.

The XAML looks like the following:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CYaPass.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CYaPass"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="515" Width="570" Background="LightGray" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="320"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock  FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center">1. Select a Site/Key</TextBlock>
            <ListView BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Aquamarine"  
                      x:Name="SiteListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="251" 
                      Margin="10,10,0,0"  Width="Auto" SelectionChanged="SiteListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListViewItem Content="Item 2"/>
            </ListView>

            <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button x:Name="DeleteSiteButton" Content="Delete Site" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="DeleteSiteButton_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="AddSiteButton" Content="Add Site" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="AddSiteButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,150,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560"/>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,-11,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" ></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" ></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" ></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox x:Name="addUppercaseCheckbox"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Add Uppercase" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="254" Click="addUppercaseCheckbox_Click" Margin="7,0,3,0"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="addSpecialCharscheckBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Add Special Chars" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,0,3,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="specialCharsTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="7,0,3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="#"/>
                <CheckBox x:Name="setMaxLengthCheckBox" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Set Max Length" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="7,0,3,0"/>
                <local:NumericUpDown Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,0,3,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="64"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center">2. Draw a pattern</TextBlock>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MainCanvas" 
                    Height="252" Width="252" Margin="7,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue" Tapped="MainCanvas_Tapped" PointerMoved="MainCanvas_PointerMoved"/>
            <Button x:Name="ClearGridButton" Content="Clear"
                    Margin="50,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="ClearGridButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

You can see the page's width is wider than the height, but when the app runs on a desktop or a simulator device (like 7" pad) the extra space is pushed into the top and the bottom.

**UWP Forced Minimum?**

Is this due to some minimum size or something that UWP forces on apps?

**Cannot Resize Smaller When Running**

Even if I grab the form's bottom or top bounding frame when the app is running, I cannot make it any smaller.

Comment: I run your code, only space I see it the bottom part, because of your last StackPanel not cover the whole page (change it to Grid and give it a background color to see)

Comment: @daylight It is because you set the height and the width of the page, so the Content is always in the Center...

Comment: @thang2410199 On another computer on VStudio 2015 running on Win10 I drop in the XAML and run it and you are right, there is no space.  The one shown that displays the space is on VStudio 2013 running as a Win8.1 UWP.  Microsoft was supposed to make this stuff run the same everywhere. There are definite gaps. Good idea on changing background color.  I will try it. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Default Content-Alignment is set to `Center` because you set the `Height` and `Width` of your Page, so your page is placed in the Center and isn't filling the whole Screen.

One Possible Solution is to add to the `Page` xaml Attributes this Piece of Code:
`VerticalAlignment="Top"`.

To set the `HorizontalAlignment` to the left add this: 
`HorizontalAlignment="Left"`.

One more advise: When you don't Need to Display more than one xaml Page at the Screen leave the Page `Height` and `Width` to Default.

Comment: Your answer got me to the solution.  You are right.  It is best to not set the page width and height.  When I did this on the Win8.1 / VStudio 2013 one then the width was autoset.  However, the height was still too long for whatever reason.  On the Win10 / VStudio 2015 it sized out exactly as expected.  Marking this as answer.  Thanks for the info.  I'll research more about it so I understand better.